# Trying to replicate the threads on a jar for the company i work for. How to extend length of the wrap

Tags: modeling, screw-modifier

[image]

This is our jar. Im trying to replicate those threads exactly. I did a screw modifier as a separate object.

Here is my model in blender [image]

heres the file
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should create the thread within the same mesh as the rest, but if we keep it as a separate mesh:

- Put your 3D cursor at the center of this object. Set the 3D cursor as the *Pivot Point*. Select a part of the mesh.

[image]

- Duplicate the selection with a <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Make the duplication rotate around the Z axis and with the 3D cursor as center.

[image]

- Delete the former thread extremity.

[image]

- Join the parts with <kbd>W</kbd> > *LoopTools* > *Bridge*.

[image]

- You've got your shape.

[image]